# What is a Random object seed

Tags: java

Halo everyone 
I've started learning java recently and i have this question what does a Random obj seed stands for ?? what does it mean ? and the difference between

Random r1 = new Random(); 
Random r2 = new Random(3);

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: Try to do a little research yourself before asking this type of question.

Comment: Not quite an exact duplicate, but will probably answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3583515/646543

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's not just a java thing.**

It's very hard to let a computer generate a real random number. Your computer needs to perform a complex unpredicatble calculation. **Your seed value will act as an input for these calculations.**

A lot of systems will use a timestamp as a seed. Because that's a value that will be different every time you run it. **But let's say you do specify a seed, and that you use the same seed multiple times:**

```
    Random rnd = new Random(10);
    System.out.println(rnd.nextInt());
    System.out.println(rnd.nextInt());
    System.out.println(rnd.nextInt());

    // do it again with the same seed
    rnd = new Random(10);
    System.out.println(rnd.nextInt());
    System.out.println(rnd.nextInt());
    System.out.println(rnd.nextInt());
```

This code will print the same 3 values 2 times.

Output:

```
-1157793070
1913984760
1107254586
-1157793070
1913984760
1107254586
```

**So, if you reuse a seed value, it will generate the same numbers.**

Answer (score 0):

By

```
 Random r1 = new Random();
```

you'll get different sequences of returned numbers between app invocations even if calling same sequences of `r1` methods with same arguments. But if your provide particular seed number, sequences of returned results will be the same (of course, only if `r2` will be invoked in same sequence of methods and arguments).

This feature is often very helpful in testing, if you perform operations on some randomly generated dataset--it allows to generate the same dataset on each test run.